# Was possibility to mix shape types in shapefiles (.shp) planned for?

Tags: shapefile, file-formats

For those who have in-depth knowledge of the definition of shapefiles and their file structure ...

Why is each and every record header followed by the shape type of the record/shape when,
by definition, it is not allowed to mix shape types in a shapefile or its set of files?

I have surmised that they perhaps planned to implement the possibility to mix shape types for future applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two valid possibilities with each shape record -- the type of the file
or a null type, so having the actual type present does serve a purpose (beyond having the type embedded in the shape binary itself).  There was *never* any intention for shapefiles to mix shape types (they were the solution to the problem of Arc/Info coverages supporting multiple topology classes).

Comment: It would be good if you could lay the focus of your answer on the explanation in your paranthesis. This seems to be the actual purpose for sacrificing the 4 Bytes each shape (record) in every shapefile.

Comment: @FlorianR.Klein I found the statement in parentheses intriguing too, and am assuming that the capability to support polygon and line topology and attributes in the same coverage was a drawback that I did not perceive.

Comment: Shapefiles were the format of ArcView -- simple and fast for those '386 machines (and novice GIS users).  Only *three* bytes are lost, and preserving word alignment was a design feature to maximize execution speed.  Shapefiles weren't only designed 20 years ago, they were *well* designed 20 years ago.